# How can I overwrite a function inside of a closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given:

```
(function() {
 function Foo() {
 }
 $.extend(Foo.prototype, {
  bar: 'hasBeer'
 });
})
```

Is it possible to change the bar method from **outside** of that closure?

Comment: Not if you don't have access to `Foo` or an instance of it. (`Foo.prototype.bar` is just a string btw ;))

Comment: @FelixKling - I have access to it I believe. This example stems from jQuery's ui library (datepicker). Yes, but what if I wanted to change the string to a function?

Comment: Need to know more. How is the outer function used? Is anything returned? Is it a namespace pattern? The outer brackets indicate self-execution, `(function(){...})();` but where is the execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the constructor function (`Foo`) and you want to override `bar` for all instances, you assign a new value to `Foo.prototype.bar`.

If you have an **instance** of `Foo`, you can either only override `bar` for that instance:

```
instance.bar = ...;
```

or for all instances by, again, overriding the prototype method. For this you have to get the prototype first, which you can do with [`Object.getPrototypeOf` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf):

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(instance).bar = ...;
```

But note that this is an ES5 method and is not available  IE <= 8 or Opera.

---

If you neither have access to the constructor, nor an instance, you cannot change the property, other than by modifying the source code.

Comment: Awesome! The second suggestion you made was perfect and I ended up with this: `Object.getPrototypeOf($.ui.datepicker).bar = function () { alert("beer"); };` which completely ran a muck. Obviously I will be putting different code there but it did its job.